# Linux detects 2 displays through I have one

Tags: kali-linux, display, multi-monitor

![I have only one VGA Connected to my monitor but kali linux detecting 2 display connected.

One eDP-1 connection and second DP-1 connection.

I don't know what is eDP-1. But it is showing as build in display.

I can only control DP-1 unknown display as unknown display for my monitor. So the resulation is damn bad :(

How could I make only one monitor detected?

[image]

Comment: eDP-1 is usually the laptop screen and DP-1 would be the external monitor.

Answer (score 0):

To tune your monitor settings, you can use the `xrandr` command.

What is the resolution of your monitor? This 1024x768 seems a little bit oldie thing for me.

- If your monitor(s) actually *have* a better resolution, then there is a driver problem.
- If not, then an `xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1025x768` switches your monitor `eDP-1` to the given resolution. The mode should exist in the `xrandr -q` output.

Other important thing from your screenshot:

- `xrandr -q` is what you wanted to give in the first command, `xrandr --q` resulted syntax error.
- Your video card may have multiple outputs, some of them can be detected while there is no monitor bound to them. You can turn them off safely with an `xrandr --output HDMI-1-OR-ANYTHING --off`.
- Sometimes your `xrandr` can't see all your possible modes, in most cases it is a driver problem or a communication problem between your monitor and video card. With the `--newmode`, `--addmode` and `--delmode` options to the `xrandr` can you correct it.